# fix 'unbroken' code with git commit and revert (my stupid way)?

Tags: git, branch, revert

I was working on `branch A` when suddenly everything crashed and stopped working. I thought I might broken something in my code so I `committed` my changes and created new `branche B` from `branch A` to keep it as a backup. then I `revert` branch `A` to the last working commit, and start trying to fix any possible bugs. I realised later that the server had a problem not my code. So I deleted branch `A` and contenue working in `branch B`. 
I did this because I'm no git expert so I sorted things out with my little knowledge. I believe there should be much easer, cleverer and more appropriate ways to solve such a problem than my "very stupid" way :)
Any suggestion?

Comment: What is stupid about it? As with many Git workflows, there's more than one way to achieve it, but the way you chose does not seem that stupid or complicated to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have reset A branch to the last working commit again,

```
git checkout branch_A
git reset --hard last_working_commit_id
```

merged the "unbroken" code from B back to A branch,

```
git merge branch_B
```

then delete B branch and continue working with A branch.

```
git branch -d branch_B
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the way you're working.  In Git, a branch is really just a pointer to a commit, and as you create more commits, the pointer moves forward with you to the last commit.  Given that, there's no difference between your original branch A and your current branch B except the name.

Now that you've deleted branch A, you can rename branch B to branch A if you like:

```
git branch -m branch-b branch-a
```

Comment: +1 That's probably better solution, mine is more complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much, this what I did now. But Lukas answer was what I'm looking for since I'm asking for an alternative to what I've done.